# code not running as expected in VS Code but working in other IDE

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, insert

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
{
    int LA[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 8};
    int item = 10, k = 3, n = 5;
    int i = 0, j = n;

    printf("The original array elements are :\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
    }

    n = n + 1;

    while (j >= k)
    {
        LA[j + 1] = LA[j];
        j = j - 1;
    }

    LA[k] = item;

    printf("The array elements after insertion :\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
    }
}
```

I have tried copying the code in other IDEs it worked but is not working in VS Code can someone help me i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: whats the meaning of "not working" ?

Comment: do you compile this as C++ ? code looks more like C

Comment: you cannot insert an element into an array. `LA` has 5 elements, you cannot change that and the last loop invokes undefined behavior for going out of bounds

Comment: In the `loop while( j >= k)` you will go out of bounds of the array `LA` (you attempt to use both element six and seven of your five-element array). That leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And a small nitpicking note: VSCode is a text-editor (with some plugins to be better handle C++ code). Neither VSCode nor any IDE's are really the programs that builds your programs, that's the job of the *compiler*. Different IDE's and different editors can use different compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters there is noting from C++ in your program.

Your program is a C program.

At least in C++ the headers should be

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cconio>
```

instead of

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
```

The array has the fixed size equal to `5`. It can not store `6` elements.

If you want to insert a new value in the array then the value stored in the last element will be lost.

So these statements

```
n = n + 1;

while (j >= k)
{
    LA[j + 1] = LA[j];
    j = j - 1;
}
```

do not make sense and lead to undefined behavior.

The program can look like

```
int a[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 };
const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

printf( "The original array elements are: " );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    printf( "a[%zu] = %d ", i, a[i] );
}
putchar( '\n' );

int item = 10;
size_t pos = 3;

if ( pos < N )
{
    for ( size_t i = N; pos < --i; )
    {
        a[i] = a[i-1]; 
    }
    a[pos] = item;
}

printf( "The array elements after insertion: " );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    printf( "a[%zu] = %d ", i, a[i] );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Pay attention to that instead of the for loop that moves values of the array to the right you could use C function `memmove`.

In C++ you could use standard container `std::vector` instead of the array.